# Laravel 5.6 Custom method to call a view

Tags: php, laravel

I have application in laravel.When I try to access a custom method using URL `localhost/blog/public/contact/myownview` it doesn't give any output. I want to redirect it to view called `video`.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactController extends Controller
{    
    //My Custom method

    public function myownview(){
        echo "yest";
        //return view('video');
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

`Route::get('/contact/myownview','ContactController@myownview');`

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: Did you map a route?

Comment: Yes I do have route in web.php

Comment: Have you set up your virtual host correctly? The root directory for Laravel is the public directory, you shouldn't need to display public in your URL.

Comment: `return response('yest');` instead of echoing... but I'm sure you could find some working code in the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers

Comment: ok I will check

Comment: No still have a same issue

Comment: Anything in laravel.log? Perhaps on the webserver (apache or ngninx) log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Route::get('/my-own-view', 'ContactController@myownview')->name('my-own-view);
```

and hit the `http://localhost:8000/my-own-view`, `<url>`+`route name`

```
return view('video');
```

**Make sure in `resources/views` file has `video.blade.php`**

Answer (score 1):

You need to custom your route.php

```
Route::get('/blog/public/contact/myownview','ContactController@myownview');
```

Comment: I have this line in web.php still can't find anything in page.Its blank

Comment: And which errors do you see when you visit this page?

Comment: Maybe you have above the route other route that give you a blank page?